# Appending turns my list to NoneType

Tags: python, mutators

In Python Shell, I entered:

```
aList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']  
for i in aList:  
    print(i)
```

and got

```
a  
b  
c  
d
```

but when I tried:

```
aList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']  
aList = aList.append('e')  
for i in aList:  
    print(i)
```

and got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "<pyshell#22>", line 1, in <module>  
    for i in aList:  
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Does anyone know what's going on? How can I fix/get around it?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`list.append` is a method that modifies the existing list. It doesn't return a new list -- it returns `None`, like most methods that modify the list. Simply do `aList.append('e')` and your list will get the element appended.

Comment: And since it doesn't return anything, you're setting aList to None if you do do the assignment, which is why you're getting the error.

Comment: All functions return something :)

Comment: true - but sometimes that *something* is `None`. But is `None` really something? My head hurts!

Comment: @kindall: "doesn't return anything" should be "in effect, it's the same is if the method doesn't have a `return` statement and returns `None` implicitly".  And.  "Methods which mutate an object almost never return a value, pop is the notable exception."

Comment: the answer "`list.append return None`" is saved my day. I was just use `aList = aList.append('e')`  and wonder why it's return `None`. Now i know the reason why, all i have to do is use `aList.append('e')`

Comment: @ThomasWouters using aList still keeps the list being called 'list', and doesn't make a new list?

Answer (score 5):

Delete your second line `aList = aList.append('e')` and use only `aList.append("e")`, this should get rid of that problem.

Answer (score 5):

Generally, what you want is the accepted answer. But if you want the behavior of overriding the value and creating a new list (which is reasonable in some cases^), what you could do instead is use the "splat operator", also known as list unpacking:

```
aList = [*aList, 'e']
#: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

Or, if you need to support python 2, use the `+` operator:

```
aList = aList + ['e']
#: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

---

^ There are many cases where you want to avoid the side effects of mutating with `.append()`. For one, imagine you want to append something to a list you've taken as a function argument. Whoever is using the function probably doesn't expect that the list they provided is going to be changed. Using something like this keeps your function ["pure"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) without ["side effects"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this error appears when you forgot to return a function at the end of another function and passed an empty list, interpreted as NoneType.

from this:

```
def func1():
  ...
  func2(empty_list)

def func2(list):
  ...
  # use list here but it interpreted as NoneType
```

to this:

```
def func1():
  ...
  return func2(empty_list)
    
def func2(list):
  ...
  # use list here, it will be interpreted as an empty List
```