# the problems related to the following code segment, initializing an empty list and append

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I write a program, including the following function, which involves initializing an empty list, and append it during iterations.

```
def build_window_sequence(x,y,windowsize):
    num_sequence = x.shape[0]
    num_size = x.shape[1]
    x_window_sequence = []
    y_window = []
    for i in range(num_sequence):
        low_index = 0
        high_index = 0
        for j in range(num_size):
            low_index = j
            high_index = low_index+windowsize-1
            current_index = low_index+round(windowsize/2)
            x_window_sequence = x_window_sequence.append(train_x[i,low_index:high_index])
            y_window = y_window.append('train_y[current_index]')
    return x_window, y_window
```

However, running the program gives the following error message

```
x_window_sequence = x_window_sequence.append('train_x[i,low_index:high_index]')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Just for more information, the involved arrays have the following shape

```
train_x shape (5000, 501)
train_y shape  (5000, 501)
```

Comment: `x_window_sequence = x_window_sequence.append(...)` <- `.append` returns `None`. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/3840784/3001761, and remember to search your error messages before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list.append` is an *in place* operation which returns `None`.

Therefore, you should append without assigning back to a variable:

```
x_window_sequence.append(train_x[i,low_index:high_index])
y_window.append('train_y[current_index]')
```

This is noted explicitly in the Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).

Comment: note that this is a very frequent duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

```
x_window_sequence = x_window_sequence.append(train_x[i,low_index:high_index])
```

Here you are assigning the result of `.append`, but `.append` does not return anything (that is, it returns `None`). You can read more [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_append.htm).